# Can't vertically align text in animated div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

I am trying to get my header that shrinks when I scroll to display my text vertically centered. For the life of me, I can't figure it out for some reason.

Here is a link to the site http://work.nickmoyer.net. I am using Bootstrap 3. I know it is something stupid that I am overlooking but I can't put my finger on it.

Thanks for any help!

**CODE BELOW**

*Navbar*

```
<div id="header_nav">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <!-- Mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services" class="smoothScroll">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/portfolio/" class="smoothScroll">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/blog/" class="smoothScroll">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </nav>
</div>
```

*Javascript to make div shrink*

```
$(function(){
  $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(document).scrollTop() > 0)
{
    if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'big')
    {
        $('#header_nav').data('size','small');
        $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
            height:'30px'
        },600);
    }
}
else
  {
    if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'small')
      {
        $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
        $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
            height:'60px'
        },600);
      }  
  }
});
```

*CSS*

```
#header_nav .navbar-default {
    background-color:transparent !important;
    border-color:transparent !important;
}

.navbar-default {
    border-color:transparent !important;
}

#header_nav {
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    position:fixed;
    background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:10;
}

#header_nav li {
}
```

Comment: Show your code here, please.

Comment: @isherwood sorry about that, its added now above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my code when it was all said and done in the js file

```
$(function(){
  $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(document).scrollTop() > 0)
{
    if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'big')
    {
        $('#header_nav').data('size','small');
        $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
            height: '30px'
        }, 600).find('a.smoothScroll').stop().animate({
            padding: '5px 15px 0'
        }, 600);
    }
}
else
  {
    if($('#header_nav').data('size') == 'small')
      {
        $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
        $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
            height:'60px'
        },600).find('a.smoothScroll').stop().animate({
            padding: '15px 15px 0'
        }, 600);
      }  
  }
});


$
```

It works for me anyway!

Comment: So you took my code, put it in your answer, and awarded yourself the accept without up-voting my answer? OK. Just checking.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Ak42Z/

```
$('#header_nav').stop().animate({
    height: '30px'
}, 600).find('a.smoothScroll').stop().animate({
    padding: '5px 15px 0'
}, 600);
```

Comment: This is defenantly a step in the right direction but when I scroll back up, the link stick to the top of the page and aren't centered again. http://work.nickmoyer.net

Comment: This code is intended to fit inside your scroll logic in two places. You'll need to reverse it as necessary.